# vb.net multiple threads to speed up my program execution

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Is it possible to use multiple threads program to speed up the process of my program?

my program is the following

1- generate a random number 
2- query by this number one remote server
3- store the result in text file

the problem is basically when i query the remote server it takes 10 seconds 
instead of waiting this time I wanted to generate 100 or 1000 number and send them separately and then when the result come I will keep them in buffer and save them later to text

any help or idea in that ?

Comment: Yes you can do it through multi threading but What you mean by  query ? can you post it?

Comment: I basically send number, for example 1087673 and the server returns full name

Comment: Using multiple threads means that your program won't wait for each request to complete before starting the next request. Whether this will be faster is unknown because the server may only be able to process one request at a time

Comment: You cannot parallelize these three steps, because each step relies on the result of the preceding one. But you can execute the sequence as a whole several times, concurrently. (Btw. you can run the first step before you do anything in parallel, because generating 100 or even 1,000 random numbers takes very little time, and perhaps you don't want to deal with the issue of synchronizing concurrent accesses to the random number generator, if ever it comes up.)

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet `Rx-Main`).

This would be your code:

```
Dim rnd = New Random()

Dim query = _
    From i In Observable.Range(0, 1000) _
    From n In Observable.Start(Function () rnd.Next()) _
    From r in Observable.Start(Function (x) CallWebService(x)) _
    Select r

File.WriteAllLines(filePath, _
    String.Join(Environment.NewLine, query.ToEnumerable()))
```

All run on background threads with maximum throughput.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

```
Module Module1

    Sub main()
        Randomize()        
        Dim r = New Random
        Dim rLock = New Object
        Dim results As New Concurrent.ConcurrentBag(Of Tuple(Of Integer, String))

        Dim getRandom = New Func(Of Integer)(Function()
                                                 SyncLock rLock
                                                     Return r.Next(0, Integer.MaxValue)
                                                 End SyncLock
                                             End Function)


        '                               total number of loops
        '                                       v
        System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, 100, Sub(i)
                                                        Dim aRandom = getRandom()

                                                        'process the query

                                                        Dim output = "-server-response-" 'or whatever the outcome of processing

                                                        results.Add(New Tuple(Of Integer, String)(aRandom, output))
                                                    End Sub)

        For Each itm In results
            Console.WriteLine(itm.Item1 & vbTab & itm.Item2)
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```